# Привязка директории стороннего репозитория

Tags: git, github

Имеем git-репозиторий на github, который зависит от сторонней библиотеки, а точнее её двух файлов в отдельной директории. Нужно эту стороннюю директорию привязать к директории в моём проекте, чтобы `git clone` и `git pull` клонировали её из стороннего репозитория.

Как я понял, это можно сделать при помощи `git subtree`, но непонятно как.

Comment: *git submodule* + `git clone --recursive`?

Comment: @Arhad Проблема в том, что надо вытащить только одну директорию, а не весь репозиторий.

Comment: А зачем? Проект, который **так** завязан на библиотеку скорее всего неправильно задизайнен.

Comment: @0andriy в моём случае это пакет совместимости lua-compat-5.2

Comment: Из того, что я знаю о Git -- никак нельзя. Не реализовано. Самым простым способом будет сделать скриптик, который запускать после клонирования с целью скачивания и установки зависимостей.

Comment: И зачем вам иметь **копию** этого у себя в репозитории?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данную ситуацию можно решить частично.

Сначала нужно настроить зависимость вашего проекта (репозитория) от репозитория библиотеки, что можно сделать двумя способами - либо `git subtree` либо `git submodule`. Работают они немного по разному, но позволят сделать так, чтобы некоторая директория в вашем проекте являлась вложенными репозиторием. Но рассматриваться с точки зрения git эти 2 варианта будут по разному. По поводу разницы в работе этих двух команд можно много где почитать, в том числе [здесь](https://briancoyner.github.io/2013/06/05/git-sparse-checkout.html). Стоит заметить, что subtree исторически более старая команда и не стоит беспокоиться, что на вашей версии git она не поддерживается, тогда как submodule более молодая.

Далее добавленный через subtree или submodule вложенный репозиторий конфигурируем таким образом, чтобы при pull сливался не весь проект, а только конкретная директория (или директории, или файлы). Для этого подойдет `git sparse checkout`, о нем можно много где почитать. Sparse как раз предназначен для настройки выборочного сливания файлов с репозитория.

Остается только одна проблема связанная с  `git pull`. Дело в том, что для обновления например subtree нужна отдельная команда вида `git subtree pull ...`. Данную проблему можно попробовать обойти с помощью 
git hook, выбрав нужный из списка возможных и написав соотвествующий скрипт на shell для обновления файлов вложенного репозитория. [Документация по hooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)

P.S Все ссылки на документацию на английском

Comment: Стоит добавить про создание символической ссылки, без неё никак.